# Zurb Foundation full body background

Tags: html, css, sass, zurb-foundation

I want to apply background to whole page. When I add code to CSS, nothing happens, but when I write some text in HTML, only part behind text is painted to color that I previously set in CSS.

I'm using Sass and when I exclude app.css, everything gets normal (because Foundation is excluded).

Here is my CSS

```
/* line 5, ../sass/master.scss */
body {
  background: url("../img/bg.png");
}

/* line 8, ../sass/master.scss */
header {
background: black;
}
```

Anybody knows solution?

Comment: What you want is `background-size: 100% 100%` . It will fill the screen with your image. More info in http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Comment: @tiagojpdias It's not working. Here is screenshot in Chrome: http://i.imgur.com/EAH8TC8.png
I thought that path is problem, but path is good. Also, when I put background on <html> then it works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `html, body { height: 100%; }`.